# Show that the five digit number abcde is congruent (mod11) to $(a + c + e) - (b + d)$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Show that the five digit number $abcde$ is congruent (mod $11$) to $(a + c + e) - (b + d)$

Comment: Observe that $$abcde = 10000 \times a + 1000 \times b + 100 \times c + 10 \times d + e.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Write your number in the form
$$e+10d+10^2c+10^3b+a10^4$$ and note that $$10\equiv -1\mod 11$$
$$10^2\equiv 1 \mod 11$$
$$10^3\equiv -1\mod 11$$
$$10^4\equiv 1 \mod 11$$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that $$abcde = 10000 \times a + 1000 \times b + 100 \times c + 10 \times d + e.$$

So $$\begin{align*} abcde - (a+c+e) + (b+d) & \equiv 9999 \times a + 1001 \times b + 99 \times c + 11 \times d\ (\text {mod}\ 11) \\ & \equiv 0\ (\text {mod}\ 11) \end{align*}$$